# Prestashop: Menu Flyout multiple columns

Tags: php, html, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

Is it possible to edit the default prestashop menu, to make it show multiple columns in the flyout when a category is being hovered when there are too many?

Comment: It probably is … but what _exactly_ you want is way too unclear.

Comment: @CBroe http://www.theaccidentalgeek.com/Portals/0/Blog/Files/1/195/Windows-Live-Writer-a5530385e3c4_9BC6-MultiColumn2_3.png something like that but in the default menu comming in presta..

Comment: Well you could simply modify the template to output sub-categories into an appropriate HTML structure …

Comment: alright i guess im gonna try that